# regex alphanum without spaces at the end/beginning of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the next regex: `^[a-z\d\-,:\s]+$`, now I need it to disallow whitespaces at the beggining of the string, so I do - `/^[a-z\d][a-z\d\-,:\s]?[a-z\d]$/i`.

**Problem:** The input may be 0,1,2+ characters, but this regex require at least 2

**Question:** how to do the same and allow zero or one character?

Comment: `[^\s]*` means zero or more none-whitespaces ;).

Comment: @shA.t `[^/s]*` means anything besides whitespace - but I need first/last symbols be one of `[a-z\d]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookarounds to disallow space at start or end:

```
/^(?!\s|.*\s$)[a-z\d,:\s-]*$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bF2jV0/2)

`(?!\s|.*\s$)` is a negative lookahead to assert that position at start and end is not a space.

Comment: `/^(?!\s|.*\s$)[a-z\d,:\s-]+$/gm.test('')` returns false but should return true. Vy string may be empty

Comment: It should be `/^(?!\s|.*\s$)[a-z\d,:\s-]*$/.test('')` to allow for empty input. See updated answer and demo.

Comment: If you are using `/m` modifier, then you should not be using `\s`, rather `^(?! |.* $)[a-z\d,: -]*$`. And never use `g` with `.test()`.

Comment: Good point @stribizhev, in fact both `g` and `m` are not needed. It is just that while building demo one needs to use them on regex101